# Rails Ancestry. How can I display a single comment with all its descendants?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

helpers/comments_helpers.rb

```
def nested_comments(comments)
    comments.map do |comment, sub_comments|
      render(comment) + content_tag(:div, nested_comments(sub_comments), :class => 'nested_comments')
    end.join.html_safe
  end

def nested_comment(one_comment)
    one_comment.instance_eval do |comment, sub_comments|
      render(comment) + content_tag(:div, nested_comments(sub_comments), :class => 'nested_comments')
    end.join.html_safe
  end
```

controllers/comments_controller.rb

```
 def show
     @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
 end
```

views/comments/show.html.erb

```
...
<%= nested_comment(@comment) %>
...
```

I keep getting this error and I don't know why:
undefined method `render' for #

If I remove the render part of the method, I get another error for content_tag

Can someone tell me how to fix these errors?

**Comments Schema**(From comments section below)

```
create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t| 
  t.text "content" 
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false 
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false 
  t.string "ancestry" 
end
```

Comment: I guess `one_comments` is a typo?

Comment: yes it is, thanks for the catch

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, since map wasn't working I looked up and found that someone else had used instance_eval. It didn't give me any errors so I didn't think anything of it

Comment: What is your schema for comments?

Comment: create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "ancestry"

  end

Comment: Your error is telling you that `render` is not a method that `Comment` has any understanding of.`instance_eval` will execute the given block in the context of the object. Which does not seem to be appropriate here. Also as a note `instance_eval` will not yield `sub_comments` ever. you could create a method for this such as `def with_sub_comments; yield(self,comments);end` this will yield the original `comment` and the `sub_comments` for that object given `comments` is an instance method of `Comment`.

Comment: without an understanding of the `Comment` object it will be difficult to help. How is a `Comment` linked to other comments?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? I am taking a stab in the dark because `Comment` is not very clearly defined.

I have never used `ancestry` before but here is a wild guess on implementation based on the documentation:

```
def nest_comments(*comments)
    comments.map do |comment|
      comment_block = render(comment) 
      comment_block += content_tag(:div, 
                                   nested_comments(*comment.children), 
                                   :class => 'nested_comments') if comment.has_children?
      comment_block
    end.join.html_safe
end
```

This will recursively run through all the comments and sub comments (beware of the extreme n+1 issues here because if sub_comments executes a new query recursively it could create performance impacts very quickly.

You should be able to call like

```
<%= nest_comments(@comment) %>
```

or

```
@comments = Comment.all
<%= nest_comments(*@comments.to_a) %>
```

The second one may have increasing performance impacts if the comments are not top level and they are called recursively multiple times but without a better understanding this question is hard to answer.

Comment: I tried the code but it doesn't work. With the ancestry gem, I can access all the subcomments with comment.descendants but the code gives me an error telling me I can't map a single Comment object. Do you know if there would just be a way to convert my single Comment object into a list that I could use the map method on? My code works for a list of comments but not a single comment

Comment: @vshivakumar if you implemented it in the exact way I notated then you should be fine `nest_comments(*comments)` will build an array of all of the objects passed e.g. `nest_comments("1","2","3")` would make the `comments` variable equal to `["1","2","3"]`. I also updated my question based on the ancestry docs. You don't want `descendant` but rather `children` for this because you want to nest them based on their direct `children` not a chain of all the childrens childrens children

Comment: @vshivakumar glad it worked for you please feel free to accept my answer.